# Как создать и вывести динамический массив строк?

Tags: c, массивы, строки, char

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать и вывести динамический строковой массив? Строку я должен сам ввести, абсолютно любую.
Я не очень силен в теме массивов, к сожалению. Есть вот такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    char a[n];

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("%d", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы на примерах покажите, что имнно хотите сделать. Пока тут нет никакого массива строк и действий со строками

Comment: Я хочу ввести какую-нибудь строку, а потом вывести её

Comment: [man getline](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (впрочем, в комментарии к ответу уже есть ссылка не нее)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ очень прост:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char buffer[1024];

    // Я хочу ввести какую-нибудь строку, 
    fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin);

    // а потом вывести её
    puts(buffer);
}
```

:-)

Comment: Все же здесь массив статический, а не динамический. И не годится для "любой строки" - если она больше 1023 символов.

Comment: @Mikhailo Если есть желание заморачиваться с **действительно динамическими** строками, воспользуйтесь функцией *getline()* - она умеет сама создавать буфера нужного размера.

Comment: У меня - ни малейшего :)